# React Custom Hooks Circular Dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, circular-dependency

I have two custom hooks i.e **useFetch** and **useAuth**. **useAuth** has all API calls methods (e.g logIn, logOut, register, getProfile etc) and they use **useFetch** hook method for doing API calls. **useFetch** also uses these methods for example logOut method when API return 401, setToken etc. So, they both need to share common methods. But that results into circular dependency and call size stack exceeded error. How to manage this

**UseFetch.js**

```
    import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
    import { AuthContext } from "../context/authContext";
    import { baseURL } from "../utils/constants";
    import { useAuth } from "./useAuth";
    
    const RCTNetworking = require("react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking");
    
    export const useFetch = () => {

      const {token, setAuthToken, isLoading, setIsLoading, logIn, logOut} = useAuth();    
      const fetchAPI = (method, url, body, isPublic, noBaseURL) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
 
        const options = {
          method: method
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        };

        return fetch(url, options, isRetrying).then(() => {
         ......
         })
       ......
      };
    
      return { fetchAPI };
    };
```

**UseAuth.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/authContext";
import { useFetch } from "./useFetch";

export const useAuth = () => {
  const {
    removeAuthToken,
    removeUser,
    setUser,
    ...others
  } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { fetchAPI } = useFetch();

  const register = (body) => {
    return fetchAPI("POST", "/customers/register", body, true);
  };

  const logIn = (body) => {
    return fetchAPI("POST", "/customers/login", body, true);
  };

  const logOut = () => {
    return (
      fetchAPI("POST", "/customers/logout")
        .catch((err) => console.log("err", err.message))
        .finally(() => {
          removeAuthToken();
          removeUser();
        })
    );
       ......
  };

  return {
    ...others,
    register,
    logIn,
    logOut,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply carry the `logOut` logic out of the `useAuth` to your `helpers` or `utils`. Use that logic both in `useAuth`'s `logOut` method and `useFetch`'s 401 condition. Since `logout` method is the only thing required from `useAuth`, you can just remove the `useAuth` hook and use `useContext(AuthContext)` to get other props.